# open txt file with 3 columns ,with a condition to check the 3rd column for difference of 5 and return that row's column 1 and 2 to a new txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm very new to coding and python and think i'm biting off more then i can chew but i am trying to create program that reads a txt file with 3 columns of information, and then takes those columns and list them.
I then want to create a condition where it compares the 3rd columns row values to the row above and below itself and if the value's difference is larger then 5 that it will copy the column 1 and 2 row where that value is found in column 3 and append it to a new list called spikes which i hopefully can create a new separate txt file with. 
example of the txt file values i have with name "xyz_test.txt":

```
98015.985   -4922343.462    101.098 
98015.985   -4922343.712    101.098 
98015.985   -4922343.962    101.093 
98015.985   -4922344.212    101.089 
98015.985   -4922344.462    108.09 
98015.985   -4922344.712    101.095 
98015.985   -4922344.962    101.093 
98015.985   -4922345.212    101.083 
98015.985   -4922345.462    101.081
```

so far what i could get and figure out is following:

```
 import csv,math listxy = [] listz = [] spikes = [] files =
 list(csv.reader(open('xyz_test.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t'))

 for z in files:
     listxy = z[0],z[1]
     listz = z[2]
     print listz
```

the results i get is following:

```
101.098 
101.098 
101.093 
101.089 
108.09 
101.095 
101.093 
101.083 
101.081
```

now i have tried to run a condition to first find that one number in list that's difference is higher then 5 to its number above and below it, but keep getting following errors:
*"not all arguments converted during string formatting"

"cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"*

Can anyone help me regarding this.

> Thanks for all the help from everyone, learned allot. i have changed
>   the code to fit what i need , here is what i ended up with. still
>   tweaking , have to create something that sorts the values and loop
>   through several txt files but this is what have so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function


import pandas as pd
# sets dipslay to larger extent
#pd.set_option('display.height', 10000000)
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000000)
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
#pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)

limit = 3
tries = 0

while True:
        print ("----------------------------------------------------")
        spikewell = float(raw_input("Please Enter Parameters: "))
        tries += 1
        if tries == 4:
            print ("----------------------------------------------------")
            print ("Entered incorrectly to many times.....Exiting")
            print ("----------------------------------------------------")
            break
        else:
            if spikewell > 50:
               print ("parameters past limit (20)")
               print ("----------------------------------------------------")
               print (tries)
               continue
            elif spikewell < 0:
               print ("Parameters cant be negative")
               print ("----------------------------------------------------")
               print (tries)
               continue
            else:
               spikewell
               print ("Parameters are set")
               print (spikewell)
               print ("Searching files")
               print ("----------------------------------------------------")





        terrain = "1_tile_test.txt"
        for df in terrain:
            df = pd.read_csv('1_tile_test.txt', sep=r'\s+', names=['____x____  ','____y____  ','____z____'])
# print orginal data frame (for testing)

# get spikes's coordinates
# df['col3'].shift(1) - previous value of the 'col3' column
# df['col3'].shift(-1) - next value of the 'col3' column
            spikes = df.loc[(df['____z____'] - df['____z____'].shift(1) > spikewell) & \
            (df['____z____'] - df['____z____'].shift(-1) > spikewell)]
            wells = df.loc[-((df['____z____'] - df['____z____'].shift(1) > spikewell)) & \
            -((df['____z____'] - df['____z____'].shift(-1)) > -spikewell)]
# print and save spikes

   # print(spikes[['col1', 'col2','col3']])
   # print(spikes2[['col1', 'col2','col3']])
   # print(wells[['col1', 'col2','col3']])
   # print(wells2[['col1', 'col2','col3']])

            spikes[['____x____  ','____y____  ','____z____']].to_csv('spikes.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
            #spikes2[['____x____  ','____y____  ','____z____']].to_csv('spikes.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
            wells[['____x____  ','____y____  ','____z____']].to_csv('wells.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
            #wells2[['____x____  ','____y____  ','____z____']].to_csv('wells.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
            print ("----------------------------------------------------")
            print ('Search completed')
            break

        break
```

Comment: You should provide the code, that causes the error. `Not all arguments converted during string formatting` means there was a string formatting operation, and `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` means there was a concatenation, neither of which are in the code you showed us.

Comment: How many rows do you expect in the output - only one with column3==108.09? Or do you need also previous and next rows as well? Please provide an example of expected output.

Comment: @gmoshkin @ MaxU sorry if gave to little info stil learning how all this works, the columns 1 and 2 are actually (x , y) coordinates and last column is z value ( height value) . so basically i want to create something that finds the spike example 108.09 between other points and then returns the x and y coordinates for that point. so the output at end that will be in a new txt file called spikes will have x and y of that specific spike z value: 98015.985   -4922344.462                             hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to take a closer look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Input data (for testing purposes i've added one row with [col3==111.110]):

```
98015.985   -4922343.462    101.098 
98015.985   -4922343.712    101.098 
98015.985   -4922343.962    101.093 
98015.985   -4922344.212    101.089 
98015.985   -4922344.462    108.09 
98015.985   -4922344.712    101.095 
98015.985   -4922344.962    101.093 
98015.985   -4922345.212    101.083 
98015.985   -4922344.462    111.110 
98015.985   -4922345.462    101.081
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=r'\s+', names=['col1','col2','col3'])
# print orginal data frame (for testing)
print(df)

# get spikes's coordinates
# df['col3'].shift(1) - previous value of the 'col3' column
# df['col3'].shift(-1) - next value of the 'col3' column
spikes = df.loc[(df['col3'] - df['col3'].shift(1) > 5) & (df['col3'] - df['col3'].shift(-1) > 5)]

# print and save spikes
print(spikes[['col1', 'col2']])
spikes[['col1', 'col2']].to_csv('spikes.csv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Output:

```
        col1         col2     col3
0  98015.985 -4922343.462  101.098
1  98015.985 -4922343.712  101.098
2  98015.985 -4922343.962  101.093
3  98015.985 -4922344.212  101.089
4  98015.985 -4922344.462  108.090
5  98015.985 -4922344.712  101.095
6  98015.985 -4922344.962  101.093
7  98015.985 -4922345.212  101.083
8  98015.985 -4922344.462  111.110
9  98015.985 -4922345.462  101.081
        col1         col2
4  98015.985 -4922344.462
8  98015.985 -4922344.462
```

spikes.csv:

```
col1    col2
98015.985   -4922344.462
98015.985   -4922344.462
```

Comment: it says "no module named pandas"

Comment: @EdwinPage, you would have to install it: "pip install pandas". http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html

Comment: @ MaxU, I got it installed!, i ran a test and it works, i tried a few tests on small list and it was fine where both the previous and next row where lower then 5 but came to issue where it seams not to pic up the spike if one of the previous or next row isnt larger then 5. i tried changing the spikes to a 'if' functions but tells me invalid syntax , and tried to use a "or" instead of the "&"  and it gives me "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." not sure what im missing

Comment: @EdwinPage, can you update your question with a sample of data where it's not working? If you want OR instead of AND ("&") in Pandas's DataFrame just use "|".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
import csv

def is_spike(three):
    first, second, third = three
    return abs(float(first[2]) - float(second[2])) > 5 and abs(float(second[2]) - float(third[2])) > 5

with open("yourcsvfile.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rows = list(reader)
    threes = zip(rows, rows[1:], rows[2:])
    spikes = [three for three in threes if is_spike(three)]

print spikes
```

Output (middle row is the "spike"):

> [(['98015.985', '-4922344.212', '101.089'], ['98015.985', '-4922344.462', '108.09'], ['98015.985', '-4922344.712', '101.095'])]

Walkthrough:

First we read the entire row data using the csv module that splits them for us. Make sure to set the delimiter properly. You can read them manually as well but this is more generic.

Secondly, we zip all `threes` (as in three rows) and check if they form a "spike" using the `is_spike` function which is rather simple.

Good luck.

Comment: @ Reut Thanks for reply! i tried your code but keeps giving me a errors message.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\test\Spike2.py", line 14, in <module>
    spikes = [three for three in threes if is_spike(three)]
  File "I:\test\Spike2.py", line 8, in is_spike
    return abs(float(first[2]) - float(second[2])) > 5 and abs(float(second[2]) - float(third[2])) > 5
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>  Not sure what doing incorrectly. must the file be csv file or can be txt with the open.("file.txt")